# Gluing result in a TQFT of Donaldson

Tags: topological-quantum-field-theory

I am reading about a (2+1)-dimensional TQFT defined by Donaldson in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911248v1), see also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04866). Below is a short summary of the construction (homology is over $\mathbb{Z}$).

---

To closed, connected, oriented surfaces $F_0,F_1$ we assign $\mathbf{F}_{DA}(F_i)=\Lambda^* H_1(F_i)$ for $i=0,1$, and to cobordisms $W$ between $F_0$ and $F_1$ such that $i_*:H_1(\partial W) \to H_1(W)$ is surjective (this holds if $H_1(W,\partial W)=\mathbb{Z}$), we assign $\mathbf{F}_{DA}(W)=|\ker i_*|:\Lambda^* H_1(F_0) \to \Lambda^* H_1(F_1)$.

Here $|\ker i_*| \in \Lambda^*(H_1(\partial W)) \cong \Lambda^*(H_1(F_0) \oplus H_1(F_1)) \cong \Lambda^*(H_1(F_0))^{\vee} \otimes \Lambda^* (H_1(F_1))$ denotes the Plücker point of $\ker i_*$, being viewed as a map $:\Lambda^* H_1(F_0) \to \Lambda^* H_1(F_1)$, defined up to a sign.

---

My question is about the functorality of this TQFT: given another cobordism $W'$ between $F_1$ and $F_2$, we have $\mathbf{F}_{DA}(W')\circ \mathbf{F}_{DA}(W)=\mathbf{F}_{DA}(W \cup_{F_1} W')$. Neither of the above two papers explicitly prove this result, perhaps indicating it should be obvious to those who are familiar with the topic. I unfortunately do not fall into that category.

I would appreciate if anyone familiar with these sorts of homology TQFTs could help me see why the functoriality should be evident, or otherwise, provide some guidance on how one might begin proving it.